# Why is Firefox 23 showing Untrusted Connection errors?

Tags: ssl-certificate, firefox

We recently went from a standard SSL certificate to a wildcard one. We use RapidSSL for our certificates. As of Firefox 23 we are getting the following untrusted connection error:

> www.safelincs.co.uk uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
>
> (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

I looked in to this and believed it to be a missing intermediate certificate, so I went to the [RapidSSL support](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=AR1548) page and downloaded the primary intermediate certificate (crt) then added the following line in to the apache config.

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt
```

After restarting apache successfully I ran an [SSL check](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/report/?fqdn=www.safelincs.co.uk&protocol=https). The path is as follows:

```
*.safelincs.co.uk -> RapidSSL CA -> GeoTrust Global CA ->Equifax
```

I thought that this would have fixed the problem, but I am still getting the error when I visit the web site: https://www.safelincs.co.uk.

I'm no expert, obviously, but can someone please point me in the right direction? This is only happening with Firefox 23 so far that we've noticed, but it's a big issue as that makes a large percentage of our sales customers.

Comment: It's a somewhat long shot, but did you clear the browser cache after changing your Apache configuration?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKjörling, yes I've had other members of the team try it on their machines too, before and after upgrading from 22 to 23. Do you get the error?

Comment: No error, first visit to your site, Firefox 23.0.1 on 64-bit Windows 7 with no relevant special setup that I am aware of, `https://www.safelincs.co.uk/` appears to show just fine. The only slight disparity I see is that I don't see the Equifax root CA in the certificate hierarchy (but I didn't look around for it either).

Comment: When I run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p (with Firefox closed) and create a new profile then check it the error is there.

Comment: That's odd. Like I said, it was a bit of a long shot. Hopefully someone else will have a better idea. (You might want to put especially that last comment into the question, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I had to use the root certificate too. On the RapidSSL site there was an [intermediate bundle](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=AR1549&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US) that I could put in the previously mentioned intermediate.crt and it sprung to life :)